# NextJs 13(app dir) fetch data from build in api

Tags: reactjs, next.js, fetch

I am using Nextjs 13 with /src and /app directory. Below I am trying to fetch data from nextjs api:

```js
//src/app/page.tsx
const getProducts = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('/api/products');
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

export default async function Home() {
....
}
```

```js
//src/pages/api/products
export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Product[]>
) {
  res.status(200).json(products)
}
```

this doesn't work and instead show `Failed to parse URL from /api/products` and `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL`.

**Note**: When I fetch the same data using localhost:3000 with url that does work perfectly fine.

I even tried using `/pages/api/products' that doesn't work either.

Comment: you can still use api routes in app directory, read more on that [here](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/api-routes)

Comment: @mocherfaoui The docs suggest using API routes in 13 exactly as the the OP did - without changing the structure from v12.

Answer (score 0):

please create `index.js` inside `/api/products/index.js` and then build your endpoint and call that from Component as you did above

e.g

```
 export default function handler(req, res) {
        res.status(200).json([{id:1, title:'T-Shirt'},{id:2,title:'Shoes'}]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks It does run they way you suggested but only I build. But in dev it throw the same error.

Comment: Please remove .next dir and try yarn or npm run dev.